# Why the universal Turing machine simulation in O(TlogT) cannot be applied to transform multi-taped Turing machine into single-taped?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, simulation, tape-complexity

Recently, I've read Hennie's Paper. I understood the construction of buffer zones, but why can't it be applied to yield a single-taped Turing machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because that UTM itself requires $2$ tapes to do its task that efficient. Removing one tape, the magic is gone.

But assuming you have the fantasy power to do efficient $1$-tape simulation, what gains do we have then?

That should be the question rather than your question.

Comment: If an efficient 1-tape simulation is possible, then the problem of verifying palindromes can be done in O(nlogn) time, which is impossible, right?

Comment: Then, computer science has more **insights** into many other **computational problems**.

Comment: But can we resolve the P vs NP problem assuming it?